# How to replace a char in a string in C?

Tags: c

I want to change a char in array of char at a specific position, I tried to assign an pointer to char to the array and dereference it to assign another value but it emit the signal SIGSEGV. it is normal ?
Here is a conceptual code :

```
int main(){
    char * hello = "Hello";
    char * ptr = hello;
    *(ptr + 1) = 'c'; //trying to change 'e' to 'c'
}
```

Thank you and have a nice day.;)

Comment: This string is in fact a *string literal*, which should not be modified (that is should be regarded as read-only), or it will cause undefined behavior. Try replacing `char * hello =..` with `char hello[] =...`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it is working now, I will check out the string literal concept :)